# Fatal Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException List is empty Error in Paging3 Android library

Tags: android, pagination, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3

I am getting this error in firebase crashlytics I cannot get additional info on that also I  am not getting where can I put try-catch or if condition guards to mitigate this issue.

Please help with this issue.

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
       at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first(_Collections.kt:212)
       at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt.first(CollectionsKt.java)
       at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.nextLoadKeyOrNull(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:560)
       at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.doLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:394)
       at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.access$doLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:54)
       at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot$collectAsGenerationalViewportHints$$inlined$collect$1.emit(Collect.kt:135)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:62)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.access$emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:1)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt$emitAllImpl$1.invokeSuspend(Channels.kt:11)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:69)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.runUnconfinedEventLoop(DispatchedTaskKt.java:204)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:282)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(BuildersKt.java:1)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(BuildersKt.java:1)
       at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.startConsumingHints(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:227)
       at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.access$startConsumingHints(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:54)
       at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot$pageEventFlow$1.invokeSuspend(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:167)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

As far as I understand with the error log is,

1. Crashing due to androidx.paging library is calling collections.first() on an empty list.
2. It's separate from main thread..so not revealing which part of the app is calling this. App currently uses pagination at 3 different places. Everywhere code is same almost, Pager.flow is used.

I have tried putting try catch in adapter code where we access the item with  `getItem(position)`. Not worked.

Any help..

Comment: You need to check collection is empty or not if empty then don't add code of Pagination

Comment: Before submitting the list ? at which level

Comment: Till submission it will be a list of pagingData<T>. We can apply map operation on that.

Comment: May be this will help you.https://stackoverflow.com/a/58726225

Comment: I am not calling anywhere ```collections.first()``` anywhere directly. Library itself calling that method without empty check

Comment: No..but the error is not popping up anywhere in the service now. I am not sure whether it's fixed or not.